Best practice for modals in Blazor
Having the need to render contents in modal windows in blazor, one could use the approach of having the popup component in the parent page with visibility set to false and so on for the components present in it. However, this implies of having the component already rendered (even if not visible) with implications on performance.
What are the best practices for rendering modal viewports in Blazor?

I wouldn't do this in Blazor.  I'd use C# conditional statements in the Layout page to determine whether to render the modal.  If you use CSS animations, they automatically start when you first display the component.

There's no such thing as "Best Practice": the best solution is one that fits your requirements and context.  Search "Blazor Modal dialog" on Bing or elsewhere for various libraries and implementations.  An article of mine on Code Project should show up that shows how to build your own - https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5286721/A-Simple-Blazor-Modal-Dialog-Implementation

To efficiently render modals in Blazor, a great practice is to use ready-made libraries that have already implemented robust and optimized solutions. Two such libraries are MudBlazor and Blazored Modal. Both provide modal components that follow best practices and solve common problems, such as handling multiple open modals. Additionally, the code is available on GitHub, is OpenSource, and contains all the code necessary for you to implement your own solutions.
You can find the complete code and more examples in the Blazored Modal repository on GitHub: https://github.com/Blazored/Modal
You can find the complete code and more examples in the MudBlazor repository on GitHub: https://github.com/MudBlazor/MudBlazor

No offense, but there are two important reasons not to default to using libraries: (1) you will miss a chance to more deeply understand Blazor; (2) 3rd-party solutions are nice when they work, but if you have a problem, you could be in reverse-engineering hell.

The use Generative AI (e.g., ChatGPT) is banned into Stackoverflow. Please, check the Stackoverflow policy about use chat gpt: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1.
